# glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When running my emulator with Android Studio I can't see anything on the emulator screen (everything is black). I get the following Event Log:

> Emulator:glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401

I already tried to clean the project and rebuild it but nothing happened. I think it's something related just with the emulator.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it's all about the emulator.

Go to Tools > AVD manager > (Edit a specific Virtual Device) > Select Cold boot

Then run again your project with that AVD. Close the session and set again Quick boot in Boot option.

Comment: Unfortunately it happens again and again since the last update. :-(

Comment: For me there is no *Boot option* in my *Virtual device configuration*

Answer (score 41):

As @SirQuickWay's solution didn't work for me I had to change *OpenGL ES Renderer* and *OpenGL ES API level* in the emulator settings to *SwiftShader* and *Renderer Maximum respectively*. You can find these settings here:

Emulator bar > ... > Settings > Advanced (tab) like this:
[Android Emulator OpenGL settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwmoY.png)

**EDIT:**
Restart of the emulator is required after applying the settings.

Comment: Worked for me as well! Thank you so much:)

Comment: Worked for me. Just had to restart the emulator after changing the settings (probably obvious for some)

Comment: Worked for me as well thanks. As a newbie, I wasn't sure where to restart the emulator. For reference, went into the AVD manager, clicked on Actions dropdown and selected 'Cold Boot Now' - all working now.

Comment: I did mine, but after my Android Emulator became slow? Have you guys encounter this?

Comment: Two years passed, but I encountered today the same problem when testing my app in the latest emulator, but on Android 7.0 image.
And this answer solved my problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My emulator was working well and then it crashed with a black screen. After that it always started with a black screen. So I went to Tools > AVD Manager > Virtual device configuration and clicked on down arrow of the last working device, made a "duplicate" of the device and deleted the original device. The new "duplicate" emulator worked.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to change the **Emulator bar > Settings > Advanced > OpenGL ES Render**
change it to **SwiftShader** then in the same Window change **OpenGL API Level** to **Renderer Maximum** then duplicate the emulator and launch it again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out that the error was as a result of me trying an emulator that runs on API 28 while the compileSdkVersion of the app is 27. Changing the API of the emulator solved it.

1. Launch the **AVD Manager**
2. Click on the **Edit** icon (pencil) of
   your device. This is in the **Actions** column
3. Click **Change** on
   the API and select one that matches your compileSdkVersion. It will download if you don't have it already.
4. Restart your emulator, and
   enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Coming to this same problem from a Visual Studio / Xamarin perspective:

1. Click on the `Open Android Device Manager` button in Visual Studio.
2. Select the emulator causing the problem and ensure that it is stopped.
3. Click the Edit button at the top to change the options.
4. Change the `hw.gpu_mode` to `swiftshader` (one of the options in the dropdown)

On my machine this was set to `guest` with a warning triangle next to it:

[image: Dialog box showing the warning triangle]

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same problem. Even I don't have option of *Boot Option* in Virtual device configuration.

My AVD was Nexus 5X with Android v26. Then I tried to upgrade version to 28(latest) but same error. Then I deleted that AVD and created new AVD with Nexus 5 skin and Android v28 and it worked.