# glTexImage2D emulator error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I keep getting an error when trying to run my app in android studio.
[Image of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik5wN.png)

Text version: "Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x502 internal 0x1907 format 0x1907 type 0x1401"

Google doesn't turn up anything. Does anyone know what it means or how to fix it?

Edit: the other solution didn't work. I'm still getting the error and the virtual device only shows a white screen.

Comment: You should check this out: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595704/glteximage2d-got-err-pre-0x506-internal-0x1908-format-0x1908-type-0x1401/50605097)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595704/glteximage2d-got-err-pre-0x506-internal-0x1908-format-0x1908-type-0x1401)

Comment: Thanks for the link but the solution didn't help. Still getting the error and the emulator still has a white screen.